# MS Access: Average with many condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

Ms Access 2020

I need to add an Average_Quantity column

```
Average_Quantity = Average of (Quantity of employees who have ticked 'x' on the Average(Y/N) column at every Day and every shift)
```

Here is the

[image: Table]

with the Average_Quantity column

I am trying to use SQL function: AVG OVER PARTITION BY  but it seems not working in SQL access

Someone could suggest any solution for this?

Comment: Hello Phong, can you put your SQL command (with OVER PARTITION clause) to see exactly what you want ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should post what you've tried and also the expected output

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you cannot use a window function -- which is the simplest method.  An alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select avg(t2.quantity)
        from t as t2
        where t2.day = t.day and t2.shift = t.shift and 
              t2.[Average(Y/N)] = t.[Average(Y/N)]
       ) as group_average
from t;
```